# Write One Xml From Other Xml in Silverlight with C#

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight

i have one xml file like this

```
<SequenceFlow>
 <FlowWriteLine> hiiii </FlowWriteLine>
</SequenceFlow>
```

I wanted to create another Xml file in silverlight with C#. XDocument is using in Silverlight. Each node in this Xml equal to another word like

SequenceFlow=WorkFlow,

FlowWriteLine=WriteLine

So when i create new Xml ,it will like this

```
<WorkFlow>
 <WriteLine> hiii </WriteLine>
</WorkFlow>
```

So how can i create new Xml using Old one..pls help me ...Advance Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply set the node name based on the current node name. 
In the sample below, I have used a dictionary for replacing the node names.

You can use any other logic that you have for replacing the node names as in mapping for original to new.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<SequenceFlow>
    <FlowWriteLine> hiiii </FlowWriteLine>
    <NotToBeReplaced>byeee</NotToBeReplaced>
    </SequenceFlow> ");

Dictionary<string, string> replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "SequenceFlow", "Workflow" }, { "FlowWriteLine", "WriteLine" } };

foreach (XElement child in doc.Root.DescendantsAndSelf())
{
    string replacementValue = string.Empty;
    if (replacements.TryGetValue(child.Name.LocalName, out replacementValue))   
    {
        child.Name = replacementValue;
    }
}
```

The above gives an output as

```
<Workflow>
  <WriteLine> hiiii </WriteLine>
  <NotToBeReplaced>byeee</NotToBeReplaced>
</Workflow>
```

Comment: hi @ryadavilli i want to add some namespace into root node.in this example it is workflow only.i tried to add by using doc.Descendants(xamlparent).FirstOrDefault().Add(new XAttribute("x:Class", "WorkflowConsoleApplication1.modify"));.but its giving error(can't inclue hexadecimal(:) charcter in attribute name).so wht i will do.i want to add more than one namespace in root node.pls sort this out.advance thanks..

Comment: What is the namespace of x here?

Comment: namespace nothing but xaml namespace only..i just want to add namespace and class name .what i mean is <Activity x:Class="WorkflowConsoleApplication1.modify"           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" 
mc:Ignorable="sap2010"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"> like this i want to add..so i will do..?