# Get All node name in xml in silverlight

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight

i created one xml like this

```
<names>
<name>
nixon
</name>
</names>
```

i want iterate each node name by foreach loop or any other loop in silverlight using xdocument.

how can i get this node name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DescendantsAndSelf() method of XElement to get all the nodes and their names.

```
foreach (XElement child in doc.Root.DescendantsAndSelf())
{
    Console.WriteLine(child.Name.LocalName);
}
```

**DescendantsAndSelf()** Returns a collection of elements that contain this element, and all descendant elements of this element, in document order.

Comment: hi..@ryadavilli thanks for your replay..can you look my previous question.pls suggest one solution for that problem.its really help for me..advance thanks.this is the link of that question..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473569/write-one-xml-from-other-xml-in-silverlight-with-c-sharp.

Comment: @nixen09 Done. Added an answer there

Comment: hi..@ryadavilli..can u look at this question..?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495569/how-to-hardcode-namespace-in-xml-in-silverlight

Answer (score 0):

With **LinqToXml**:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(mySmlString);
var names = xDoc.Root.Elements("name").Select(x=> x.Value.Trim()).ToArray();
foreach (var name in names)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```