# How to HardCode String in Xml in Silverlight

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight

i am new to xml in silverlight.i have one small xml file below

```
<FlowActivities>

 <SequenceFlow >

  <FlowWriteLine>

         hiiii

  </FlowWriteLine>

 </SequenceFlow>

</FlowActivities>
```

in this i want to hardcode some namespace in rootnode.like

```
<FlowActivities x:Class="WorkflowConsoleApplication1.modify" 
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" 
      mc:Ignorable="sap2010"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      sap2010:ExpressionActivityEditor.ExpressionActivityEditor="C#"
      xmlns:sap2010="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2010/xaml/activities/presentation"
      xmlns:sco="clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=mscorlib"   
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

 <SequenceFlow >

  <FlowWriteLine>

         hiiii

  </FlowWriteLine>

 </SequenceFlow>

</FlowActivities>
```

for getting this wht i have to do..? pls sort this out..?

Comment: have you tried anything yourself. I mean with a little copy paste and changing rules one by one and see what happens you should get pretty far yourself...

Comment: @BartTeunissen i tried. i try to add attribute of flowactivity then it make error like attribute value can't contain hexadecimal(:) value.so i can't add..

Answer (score 1):

**XAML is not a current XML file**, is a language based on XML. Therefore you can not write random, non-existent XML tags.

To hardcode a string in SL XAML file:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Test_SL_HardcodeString.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <system:String x:Key="myString">This is a test string</system:String>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBox Text="{StaticResource myString}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: hi..@joan..i am new to xml ..can u look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496991/how-to-add-hexadecimal-value-in-xarrtribute-name-in-xml..its really helpful 4 me..

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You have to set the variable like JoanComasFdz said. 
If you must use the same format, you can create a separate class(viewmodel) for eg. MyXMLData.cs to read and parse xml file. Read the XML node and set the class variable "theString" from this class. In XAML, you can create an instance of the class in the resources section and set the data context of the Grid or the textbox to that object.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Test_SL_HardcodeString.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace.ViewModels"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <viewmodel:MyXMLData x:key="myxmldataclass"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" DataContext="{StaticResource myxmldataclass}" >
        <TextBox Text="{StaticResource theString}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: hii @aaa can u look this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496991/how-to-add-hexadecimal-value-in-xarrtribute-name-in-xml..