# How To Add ":" (namespace prefix) in XAttribute Name in Xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

i have one xml file and using in silverlight.

```
doc.Descendants(xamlparent).FirstOrDefault().Add(new XAttribute("x:Class","WorkflowConsoleApplication1.modify"));
```

but in this ":" hexadecimal cause error.how can i add this hexadecimal in attribute name.is this possible ?.

Answer (score 1):

You have to see the URI of the namespace which is mapped to the `x` namespace prefix. Check out the top of your XML document, it will contain something like `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`.

Then, you instantiate the `XAttribute` using the full XML namespace URI from above like so:

```
new XAttribute(XName.Get("Class", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"), "WorkflowConsoleApplication1.modify")
```

Further reading:

- [XName.Get Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299741.aspx)
- [XML namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) on Wikipedia