# c# How to know the root and child node names dynamically in xml in silverlight

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have xml stored in a string suppose like this:

```
String xmlString =
<A>
  <B>
     <C>C1</C>
     <D>D1</D>  
  </B>
  <Separator>S1</Separator>
  <B>
     <C>C2</C>
     <D>D2</D>
  </B> 
</A>
```

I wann know the name of each child node names from c# code.

I mean i will not have xml code it will come randomly to me so i don't know what is the xml structure and i wanna know all the child node names like A,B,Cand D here.

I mean i want to have something like which starts from the head/Parent( in lmy xml) and ends at the last(I mean  in my xml) and prints one by one all the node like `A,B,C,D,Separator, then again B ,C,D`.

What i tried is this :

```
         IEnumerable<XElement> de = from el in xmlstring.Descendants() select el;
         foreach (XElement el in de)
         {
             Debug.WriteLine(el.Name);
         }
```

but it gives error :

```
Error   1   The type 'char' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Xml.Linq.Extensions.Descendants<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)'. There is no boxing conversion from 'char' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XContainer'.   
Error   2   Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'.  'Select' not found.  Are you missing a reference or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?
```

Both the error corresponds to `xmlstring.Descendants()` with red underline by Visual studio.

I HAVE THE FOLLOWING REFERENCES: (i amean i already have required refernces like Linq,xml etc.):

[image]
**Note: I am working in silverlight and i have to write this code in c#.**

Thanks would be a big help.

Comment: "give a piece of code for reference" sounds like "do my work for me". Have you tried *anything* yet? If you can use LINQ to XML, this is very straightforward - look at the `Descendants` method, for example. It's also not clear what you mean by "root child node" in the title....

Comment: Just for clarification, node names, **not** the values. Correct?

Comment: @JonSkeet root child means root and child both must be printed  step by step.

Comment: @user234839: So you mean "all node names"? It's still unclear...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I wish to have all node names step by step as i moves down in xml until i encounter with </A>(i mean end of xml)

Comment: Right, so what have you tried? Again, this sounds like the `Descendants` method to me...

Comment: var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlstring);
                 XNode root = doc.FirstNode;

Comment: But the first line gives error that couldn't load xml (I mean var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlstring);)

Comment: You want `XDocument.Parse(xmlstring)`

Comment: @bubbinator but i guess my approach to do this is wrong. Could you please explain your ideas to achieve this ?

Comment: @user234839 You're learning still and you are heading in the right direction. `Load` is for getting files out of storage. `Parse` is for converting a `string` into `xml`. If you are getting an error with `Parse`,  then post the exception message. Oh, it wouldn't hurt to edit your code containing the `string`. You don't have quotes or `@` up there.

Comment: @bubbinator and Jon Please see th edited question that shows what i tried to do and what is the error.

Comment: @user234839 For error 1: you tried to use `Descendants` on a string. Error 2: you probably need to put `using System.Linq;` in your code file.

Comment: @bubbinator i already have please see the snap shot i recently addded.And how to make the solution for thez first error , actually i am following this link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You need to reference `System.Linq` in the solution and in the code file still. `System.Xml.Linq` won't cover all of it.

Comment: @bubbinator I solved it but first error still persists. what to use instead of XmlString(string variable) which ocntains the xml for which element names are to be obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet so i'm gonna write here: `System.Xml.Linq` is what you need for 
XmlDocument.Descendants, not `System.Linq`.

[Get All node name in xml in silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476744/get-all-node-name-in-xml-in-silverlight)

^That is what you're looking for.
I used this code and it printed the node names just fine.

```
    string xml = "<A><B><C>C1</C><D>D1</D></B><Separator>S1</Separator><B><C>C2</C><D>D2</D></B></A>";
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    foreach (XElement child in doc.Root.DescendantsAndSelf())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(child.Name.LocalName);
    }
```

Comment: please see the added snap shot in the asked question. I already have it

Comment: actually i added Syestem.Linq (which was missing and it worked :P ) But still one error. Error 1 The type 'char' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Xml.Linq.Extensions.Descendants<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)'. There is no boxing conversion from 'char' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XContainer'.

Comment: @Ansad thanks for the answer but its a silverligth application. It dont support XmlDocument.

Comment: what is "doc" on this link and how to obtain this doc from my xml string variable XmlString which contains the xml ?

Comment: doc is a XDocument variable. You declare it like this: XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);

Comment: but i have xml in String variable called xmlString . Not in XDocument.

Comment: Actually, yeah, my bad. XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

Comment: @user234839 Since you are dealing with a string and not a file: `var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring)`. That link has your answer for the most part. However it will print _everything_ in one shot, _not_ the tiered way you want.

Comment: @bubbinator your one line replaced in Asad's given link worked for me thanks both of you.

Comment: @user234839 I tried it the way you said and it still works for me. I'll add the code above.

Comment: @AsadAli Ok let me see that as well

Comment: yes you are right . i was doing something like XDocument doc = new XDocument(xmlString) a,d it was generating exception. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: @AsadAli Thanks, I have one small doubt what if i just have to see the child of just Root class ? I mean just it must print B,Separator,and B again .

Comment: Just change the code a little bit to this:                        `foreach (XElement child in doc.Root.Nodes()) {
                Console.WriteLine(child.Name.LocalName); }`

Comment: Bravo..............Big thanks. But i dont know why i have negative for this question.