# How to get the name of the child node in xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml

My XML looks like this

```
<Location>
    <AChau>
        <ACity>
          <EHouse/>
          <FHouse/>
          <GHouse/>
        </ACity>

        <BCity>
          <HHouse/>
          <IHouse/>
          <JHouse/>
          <KHouse/>
        </BCity>
    </AChau>
</Location>
```

I find a number of ways, I am here to find the closest answer

[Get All node name in xml in silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476744/get-all-node-name-in-xml-in-silverlight)

But it reads all the descendants, I need is from "Location" get "AChau"

From "Location/AChau" get "ACity" "BCity"

From "Location/AChau/ACity" get "EHouse" "FHouse" "GHouse"

How can I read only child node?

Comment: You mean, [XmlNode.ChildNodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? And if you want only the first one, use `[0]`. I'm not sure where Silverlight comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have an `XElement`, you can extract the array of names of its children using the following code:

```
string[] names = xElem.Elements().Select(e => e.Name.LocalName).ToArray();
```

For example, this code with your XML:

```
public static MyXExtensions 
{
    public static string[] ChildrenNames(this XElement xElem)
    {
        return xElem.Elements().Select(e => e.Name.LocalName).ToArray();
    }
}

string[] names1 = xDoc.Root.ChildrenNames();
string[] names2 = xDoc.Root.Element("AChau").ChildrenNames();
string[] names3 = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("Location/AChau/ACity").ChildrenNames();
```

will return the following arrays respectively:

```
["AChau"]
["ACity", "BCity"]
["EHouse", "FHouse", "GHouse"]
```

Comment: I'm trying, but he appeared error message'You can not System.Xml.Linq.XName [] 'convert' string [] '

Comment: @AM031447 I have updated the code 5 minutes earlier by adding `LocalName`. Have you tried this?

Comment: names1 and names2  is work! but names3 appeared another error message'XDocument 'not included' XPathSelectElement 'definition, can not find the expansion method' XPathSelectElement '

Comment: I tried to rewrite names 2 "Root.Element (" AChau / ACity ") Children Names ();." But does not work

Comment: @AM031447 you need to import XPath extensions. What about Element("AChau/ACity") - it is an incorrect syntax.

Comment: oh i found! And it works! Now I can get the name of any node, thank you: D

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `XElement` to get your data from xml - then all you need is [FirstNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.firstnode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property and [Elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.elements(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

`FirstNode` returns first child node of element and `Elements` returns all direct child nodes of element.

Answer (score 1):

This works if you always want the first node name under the root:

```
string xml = @"<Location>
              <AChau>
                <ACity>
                  <EHouse/>
                  <FHouse/>
                  <GHouse/>
                </ACity>

                <BCity>
                  <HHouse/>
                  <IHouse/>
                  <JHouse/>
                  <KHouse/>
                </BCity>
              </AChau>
            </Location>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode first = root.FirstChild;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = 
                "<Location>" +
                    "<AChau>" +
                        "<ACity>" +
                          "<EHouse/>" +
                          "<FHouse/>" +
                          "<GHouse/>" +
                        "</ACity>" +
                        "<BCity>" +
                          "<HHouse/>" +
                          "<IHouse/>" +
                          "<JHouse/>" +
                          "<KHouse/>" +
                        "</BCity>" +
                    "</AChau>" +
                "</Location>";

            XElement location = XElement.Parse(xml);

            var results = location.Descendants("AChau").Elements().Select(x => new
            {
                city = x.Name.LocalName,
                houses = string.Join(",",x.Elements().Select(y => y.Name.LocalName).ToArray())
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
​
```